# Слияние: png + gif + gif +png

Tags: python, изображения, png, gif

Задача: требуется объединить (т.е. наложить друг на друга две анимированных gif, одну png с прозрачным фоном и фоновую png).

Пытаюсь реализовать это на Python через PIL. Пока получилось добавить фон к одной gif, но такое ощущение что я через пятку чешу ухо - сначала разбил gif на фреймы, объединил каждый фрейм с фоном, объединил все фреймы в одну gif. Но таким методом наложить две gif одна на другую не получится.

Есть ли какие-то действенные методы сделать это? Рассматриваю любые способы и языки (не обязательно Python), но обязательно в виде кода.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

С помощью Python Pillow можно так сделать. К примеру:

```
from PIL import Image
 
im1 = Image.open('fon.jpg')
im2 = Image.open('guido-van-rossum.jpg')
 
im1.paste(im2)
im1.save('fon_pillow_paste.jpg', quality=95)
 
im1.close()
im2.close()
```

По умолчанию изображение вставляется в верхней левой части фоновой картинки.

Если Вы хотите узнать о такой теме подробнее, то рекомендую почитать эти статьи: [Как вставить одно изображение в другое используя Pillow](https://python-scripts.com/pillow-paste), [Используем Python Pillow для вставки текста и изображения в картинку](https://fixmypc.ru/post/vstavka-teksta-i-izobrazheniia-v-kartinku-s-python-pillow-pil/) и [Простое наложение изображений в Python](https://defpython.ru/prostoe_nalozhenie_izobrazhenii_v_Python). Лично мне очень нравится первая статья.

Comment: Если вы прочитаете внимательно то, что я писал, то увидите что требуется не просто одну картинку на другую вставить.

Comment: А в чём проблема? Я Вам уже на всё ответил. Просто добавьте новые переменные и укажите расширение необходимого файла. А вообще то, что Вы хотите проще добиться в Photoshop. Там есть все необходимые для этого средства.

Comment: То что вы предлагаете с анимированными gif не работает.

Comment: Вы внимательно прочитали мой ответ и статьи приложенные к нему?

Comment: А Фотошоп и прочие редакторы мне не подходят, потому что необходимо чтобы данный процесс шел автоматически без участия человека

Comment: Я внимательно прочитал данные статьи ещё 2 дня назад, когда стал изучать данный вопрос. И в них кстати ни слова нет про анимированные gif и их объединение. Вы пробовали сами две гифки объединить в одну?

Comment: Может быть Вам создать Gif-изображение с помощью Pillow, а затем получившийся результат объединить с Jpg/Png-изображениями. А вообще, как Вы сами написали: Вы пытаетесь "через пятку чесать ухо". Проще это сделать вручную, а не морочиться с кодом.

Comment: Во-первых, в любом случае благодарю вас за помощь. Когда я объединяю анимированную gif с фоном в формате png с помощью .paste, то получается статическая gif без анимации. Ещё раз хочу сказать, что мне не подходит ручной способ.

Comment: Ясно. Тогда удачи!